# Mongodb: Querying array of subdocuments

Tags: arrays, mongodb, subdocument

I have users' collection whose schema is like:

```
{
  _id: unique number,
  name: 'asdf',
  age: '12',
  gender: 'm',
  address: [
    {area: 'sdf',
     city: 'sdq', 
     state: 'wfw'},
    {area: 'asdf',
     city: 'sdfs',
     state: 'vfdwd'}
  ]
}
```

I want to find out the users for whom all the values of `state` in `address` should be the value I pass. If even one of the `state` value doesn't match with the value I pass the user shouldn't be returned.
I tried simple find, aggregation framework with `$unwind`, `$match` but nothing seemed to get solution. Can you please help me out...

Thanks

P.S. please bear with multiple addresses for the sake of question. :)

Comment: can you paste your document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand.

I replicated your document. When you want to retrieve an user by `state` you can do in many ways

If you search with single value you can do

```
db.g.find({ "address.state": "wfw" })
```

and retrieve an user

You can use `$all`

```
db.g.find( { "address.state": { $all: ["wfw","vfdwd"] } } ) // retrieve User

db.g.find( { "address.state": { $all: ["wfw","vfdwd","foo"] } } ) // don't retrieve User
```

or you can use `$and`

```
db.g.find( { $and: [ { "address.state":"wfw" },{ "address.state":"vfdwd" }] } )
```

But I don't know if I understand your question

**Update and the correct answer**

```
db.g.find( { "address.state": { $nin: ["wfw"] } } )
```

Let me Know

Comment: Hi Barno. This is what I had tried. But it didn't seem to give me desired solution. Anyway thanks for your help. Regarding the question, I want to retrieve the users who don't have any of the state address matching the value I pass. For eg- users who haven't stayed in the state 'wfw' yet. In this case the query should return me the users who don't have any of the state address matching 'wfw'. Got it?

Comment: @harshad Maybe Now I understand. Something like `db.g.find( { "address.state": { $nin: ["wfw"] } } )` ?

Comment: Thank you very much Barno. You got it! It seems to work. Got a relief. :)

Comment: nice ! http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/
you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

To find out if all array entries match the state "wfw", do an aggregation like the following:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$project" : {
        "test" : {
            "$allElementsTrue" : [{
                "$map" : { 
                    "input" : "$address", 
                    "as" : "a", 
                    "in" : { "$eq" : ["wfw", "$$a.state"] }
                }
            }]
        }
    } },
    { "$match" : { "test" : true } }
])
```

This aggregation takes each document, maps "state equals 'wfw'" over the address array to get a boolean array, and tests if the entire array is true, storing the result in `test, and then filtering the results based on test. You will need MongoDB 2.6 for support of some of the operators.

Comment: What different with $all?

Comment: `$all` checks that all the elements of the array argument to `$all` are present in the array field, not that all of the elements of the array field are among the elements of the array argument to `$all`. For example, `{ "$all" : [1, 2, 3] }` matches `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, not `[1, 2]`. It's not what the OP needs.

Comment: hi wdberkeley. thanks for your solution. I tried it, but it shows following exception. Can you figure out why- failed: exception: $allElementsTrue's argument must be an array, but is NULL

Comment: Also I have one doubt: can we have multiple $match stages in aggregation? I have this condition where result of one query should be forwarded to next query & so on (because queries are prioritized) & those queries are of comparison in nature. Aggregation framework seems to be best suitable solution for this type of problem, (because of pipeline). But if there is any other way you can suggest I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yup, you can have multiple `$match` stages. It's best to condense into one query if possible, I'd say, because only the first match will be able to use indexes.